# What's the meaning of "this" keyword here?

Tags: c#, c++, this

A very short C# function.

```
    public static int SizeInBytes(this byte[] a)
    {
        return sizeof (int) + a.Length*sizeof (byte);
    }
```

What does "this" keyword mean in this function? What's the equivalent of this keyword in C++? Besides, what is this function trying to calculate exactly?

Comment: C++ has free functions, extension methods would be far from idiomatic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It marks the method as an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

An extension method allows you to extend the functionality of any class, even if it's sealed.

Example:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool IsEmpty(this string s)
    {
        return s == string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Note the proper syntax includes a static method, in a static class, and the use of the **this** keyword.

For your second question, there is an equivalent of **this** in C++..... it's **this**. However, C++ does not support extension methods, so you'll never see it in C++ as in the code snippet you provided.

Comment: can you give more info about this? and what does this refer if it is used other than that

Answer (score 7):

It is the syntax used for [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) in C#. This is **not** C++.

It means that if you have a `byte[]` represented by the variable `buffer`, and the extension method is in scope (namespace imported, for example), you could do the following:

```
int buffSize = buffer.SizeInBytes();
```

This syntax is pure [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) - the compiler converts this to a call to the static method (on the required static class), passing in the `byte[]` as the first parameter. As such, you can write the equivalent in C++, but not get the nice syntactic sugar the C# compiler gives you.

Comment: Er, I mean, if I want to implement this behavior of "extension method" into C++, is it possible?

Comment: @derekhh - I am not aware of a way to do so.

Comment: @derekhh: C++ has Koenig lookup (aka "Argument Dependent Lookup"), which is more powerful than C# extension methods.